# c# linq Include with parameter value

Tags: c#, linq

I have created a static method that only shows items where `Deleted = false` and it looks like this:

```
public static IQueryable<T> OnlyActive<T>(this IQueryable<T> items, bool active = true) where T: BaseModel => items.Where(m => m.Deleted != active);
```

I use this throughout my application:

```
return _databaseContext.Categories.OnlyActive()
```

I have since realised that that works fine, but if I use an include, then it doesn't.
I have this method:

```
public class GenericListHandler<TContext, T, TKey> : IRequestHandler<GenericList<T, TKey>, Attempt<IQueryable<T>>>
    where TContext: DbContext
    where T : BaseModel, IKey<TKey>
{
    private readonly TContext _databaseContext;
    public GenericListHandler(TContext databaseContext) => _databaseContext = databaseContext;

    public async Task<Attempt<IQueryable<T>>> Handle(GenericList<T, TKey> request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        var query = request.Take > 0 ? _databaseContext.Set<T>().OnlyActive().OrderBy(m => m.Id).Skip(request.Skip).Take(request.Take) : _databaseContext.Set<T>().OnlyActive();
        
        var includes = request.Includes;
        if (includes.Length == 0) return Attempt<IQueryable<T>>.Succeed(query);

        query = includes.Aggregate(query, (current, include) => current.Include(include));

        return Attempt<IQueryable<T>>.Succeed(query);
    }
}
```

As you can see, it lists a **model**. If there are no includes, it only lists the active ones.
If there are includes, it only lists the active models, but not the includes.

I would like to write a method that checks the includes and makes sure they are not deleted also.
Does anyone know how I can do this?

Comment: Have you heard about Global Query Filters? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/querying/filters
While it is possible to implement such includes, custom filter will work only with Collection properties.

Comment: No I haven't. Is that article saying I if add that `IsDeleted` (in my case just `Deleted`) to OnModelCreating, all queries will only include items that are not deleted?

Comment: Have you tried this without using your generic method? I cannot see how adding the deleted filter would affect the includes.

Comment: @r3plica, yes. But when you need deleted entities - use `IgnoreQueryFilters`

Comment: You are a star :)

Comment: Can you add your link as an answer and I will mark it

Comment: While I do recommend using query filters, I'm not sure how it answers your question? I cannot see how your query breaks like you say it does.

Comment: I get what you are saying, but it negates the need for my `OnlyActive` extension method and also means I don't have to create a new extension method for `Include`. It provides a better solution and Svyatoslav has correctly identified that I am creating a soft delete solution

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use Global Query Filters https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/querying/filters
which will filter out deleted entities automatically.

For disabling query filter, just add `IgnoreQueryFilters()` function to your query.